# How can I achieve the same angle of bevel on the inset face?

Tags: modeling, bevel

How can I make the bevel so that the length of the blue line is the same as the green one?

[image: Screenshot]

[image: Reference]

[image: Before bevel]

[image]

Comment: Can you fill in a couple of details.. how you achieved this inset, with any settings, and whether the scale of your object is applied? (I'm having trouble reproducing this effect) Inset with 'Offset Even' should be just that.

Comment: @RobinBetts, the offsets from the vertices are, but this is not considering the inner/outer edges as indicated in the question. In fact, I don't think its possible using bevel of inset, but that needs manual operations (like scaling a circle)... but I may have wrong (?)

Comment: Have you scaled the object in _Object Mode_ and did not apply the scale (`Ctrl`+`A`)? Without telling us what you did we cannot tell where you went wrong.

Comment: Nothing wrong in the question: just give it a try

Comment: Hi, @lemon I must be being dim in my understanding of the problem...  [what am I missing](https://imgur.com/a/LaUD9rY)  .. ?

Comment: mmm... @RobinBetts, so why? https://i.stack.imgur.com/nzABD.png

Comment: @lemon .. mmm ... included settings, this time .. https://imgur.com/a/OwJa9gT Ahhhh.. OK, you're bevelling, I'm insetting?

Comment: Started from a rectangle, inset a face and moved it along the normals of the face (like in the reference picture) (of course scale is applied)

Comment: @AlexJanaqi Moved it along the normals of the face? Sorry I don't understand what you did. When you inset the face it should automatically work correctly. Is it possible to show settings? Because I do not get your result with insetting.

Comment: @lemon I figured I had to apply beveling first, and then to inset the other face

Comment: Beveling first why not (@RobinBetts) but that change nothing: the result won't be perfect (green line not equal blue line). To have the result, you may delimit the angles (after the vertex bevel) then inset with "edge rail" option.

Comment: @lemon awesome. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Well...many many comments over this (should be) simple question.

The only way I've found (in order to have green and blue line the exact same length) is the following:

First bevel at some steps:

[image]

Mark the limits, whatever the bevel is, join <kbd>J</kbd> the outer parts of the previous bevel:

[image]

Then inset, with 'edge rail' option:

[image]

So that all length , are the same:

[image]

Comment: Of course you could introduce some "guide lines" to make it better. I just think that we are taking the word "same" in the question too literal. Because what is shown in the question is a green edge that is strikingly different in length from the blue one, which is really apparent - whereas the reference object would not look too incorrect when done with my method. After all, you are too precise here I guess since in the question the horizontal distance (the blue line) is not even the same length as the vertical distance between outer and inner edge but that didn't seem to bother the OP...

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann, I don't know what the OP wants really. I just tried to provide accurate answer... useless, maybe ;)

Comment: By the way, you're last edit: "in order to have green and blue line the exact same length" - when I just inset horizontally in the same plane without depth as you do here, my edges are (so far) always the same length as well... only going up diagonally there are sometimes rounding errors. "Same length" does not necessarily mean they have to be parallel to the borders ;) Anyway, that's a good accurate answer+1 Mine is the more quick and dirty and still good enough for simple models :D

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann, yes... the op will know what he wants

Comment: Of course there is something that totally slipped my attention: as Robin pointed out, the inset (without guiding lines at least) is not a circle arc - that's why you got a different result from me, because the less bevel segments, the less parallel the last edges are, the worse the error. You had only 4 segments, I had 12. The OP has 30 in his screenshot, so I guess it will be almost as exact as your result.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann, anyway, you should keep your answer opened, I think. Just explain the point.